# ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras==2.3.1

Tags: python, azure, keras

I am trying to use Keras==2.3.1 while running a pipeline on the Azure, but it looks that this specific version cannot be found? There is no newest version 2.4.3 either. These versions don't look to be on the version list. If I use Keras without specified version, it installs 2.4.2. The full error:

```
    ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement keras==2.3.1 (from ****-dev) (from versions: 0.2.0, 0.3.0, 0.3.1, 0.3.2, 0.3.3, 1.0.0, 1.0.1, 1.0.2, 1.0.3, 1.0.4, 1.0.5, 1.0.6, 1.0.7, 1.0.8, 1.1.0, 1.1.1, 1.1.2, 1.2.0, 1.2.1, 1.2.2, 2.0.0, 2.0.1, 2.0.2, 2.0.3, 2.0.4, 2.0.5, 2.0.6, 2.0.7, 2.0.8, 2.0.9, 2.1.0, 2.1.1, 2.1.2, 2.1.3, 2.1.4, 2.1.5, 2.1.6, 2.2.0, 2.2.1, 2.2.2, 2.2.3, 2.2.4, 2.2.5, 2.3.0, 2.4.0, 2.4.1, 2.4.2)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for keras==2.3.1 (from ****-dev)
```

What could be an issue?

Comment: `pip install Keras==2.3.1`

Comment: tried to add "subprocess.check_call([sys.executable, "-m", "pip", "install", "keras==2.3.1"])" before a setup() function from setuptools, but no luck with that

Comment: you a `requirements.txt` file to install all dependencies

Comment: tried to use requirements.txt file, but had problems with Tox, so passed install requirements as a list to the setup() function

Comment: @Bhargavi Annadevara According to the page you added, it was 7 Oct 2019

Comment: @LaurynasG Where are you trying to install Keras? What pipeline is this?